# how to use input[type=range] CSS Pseudo-elements with firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an input with a `type="range"` attribute that needs to act as a 'seekbar' for a custom html 5 video player.
i've got all the `-webkit...` things working (except for buffering...) and i'm trying to recreate them for FF and IE (10 and 11), what would be the best way?

here is the css i've got:

```css
input[type=range] {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 0px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: -8px 0 0 0;
 padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: visible;
 width: 100%;
 background: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 position: relative;
 pointer-events:none;
 width: 4px;
 height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 0px 1.8px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.1);
    border: 0.4px solid rgba(30, 170, 241, 0.57);
    background: #1eaaf1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 background: #757575; 
 height: 4px;
 margin:5px 0;

}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
 content:"-";
 font-style: 0;
 line-height:0;
 position: absolute;
 left:-3000px;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 background: red;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left:-8px;
 right:-8px;
 top:-8px;
 bottom:-8px;
 background: red;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index: 10;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
 outline:none;
}
input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb:after,
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
 background: red;
}
input[type=range]:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
 background-color: #a1151a;
}
input[type=range]:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
 background: #adadad !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

here is a jsFiddle for that as well: http://jsfiddle.net/goldzimer/yttap7qj/

thanks in advance!

**Update:** after adding some css for Firefox and IE i am now at a point where only on Firefox i can't get the effect of having the left side with one color and the right side with another.

Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goldzimer/yttap7qj/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudo selector you're after for the fill on FF is `::-moz-range-progress`

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried these solutions ?

```
::-moz-range-track 
::-moz-range-thumb. 
::-ms-track
::-ms-fill-lower
::-ms-fill-upper
::-ms-thumb
```

http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: the `::-moz-range-track` and `::-moz-range-thumb` only take you so far, i'm trying to get the effect of the bar filling as you move it like in the snippet on chrome